# PHP: failed to open stream: Invalid argument

Tags: php, https, file-get-contents

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudplus/us-east-1%3A4eddd3f9-3729-473f-984c-16fddfe5e23f/Contacts/Contacts_1436328498.vcf');
?>
```

I don't know why is show error like this  [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument

Comment: its working fine. Just `print_r($file);` to see the result.

Comment: have you enabled `allow_url_fopen` in your `php.ini`? @SHAZ - don't you mean `print $file` since the returned value is not an array?

Comment: @cyclone   I don't know how to do that  sir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure so that you have `allow_url_fopen` enabled in your `php.ini` file.

To edit your `php.ini` file an check if `allow_url_fopen` is enabled you could check the output of `phpInfo()` to find the location of your `php.ini` file and then open this file in a text editor and search for `allow_url_fopen` and make sure so this is set to `On`.

To find the location of your `php.ini` file you could do like this from the terminal:

```
php -r 'phpInfo();' | grep php.ini
```

When you have located the file you can edit it using a text editor like `nano` for instance:

```
sudo nano /etc/private/php.ini
```

After you have modified your configuration file make sure so you restart apache using:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

You may also check if there is any suitable wrappers for `https`:

```
$wrappers = stream_get_wrappers();
echo 'openssl: ',  extension_loaded  ('openssl') ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'https wrapper: ', in_array('https', $wrappers) ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'wrappers: ', var_dump($wrappers);
```

If no `https` wrapper is enabled and you're running windows you should again edit your `php.ini` file and uncomment this line:

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Just like before, you need to restart your server for the changes to take effect.

Comment: openssl: no https wrapper: no wrappers: array(6) { [0]=> string(3) "php" [1]=> string(4) "file" [2]=> string(4) "data" [3]=> string(4) "http" [4]=> string(3) "ftp" [5]=> string(13) "compress.zlib" }  It show like this

Comment: @KeeratiPongram - Are you running windows? Then like I stated in my updated answer, you should edit your `php.ini` and uncomment this line `extension=php_openssl.dll` by removing the leading `;` character. Notice that you then need to restart your server for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Yes i run on Windows  , I already fixed  by remove ; front of extension=php_openssl.dll   but still  show error .

Thank you for your help sir.

Comment: I think I can help you better in a chat, go to this room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80848/drupal-7

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following function:

```
print_r
```

So your code looks like this:

```
<?php
$file = https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudplus/us-east-1%3A4eddd3f9-3729-473f-984c-16fddfe5e23f/Contacts/Contacts_1436328498.vcf;
print_r($file);
?>
```